# jQuery click events in Bootstrap Button plugin

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

How can I determine which radio button is checked on click of a radio button using the [Bootstrap Button plugin](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/buttons/#button-plugin)?

The following is evaluating to false no matter which radio button is selected:

HTML

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" id="disabled-radio-btn">
    <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="disabled" id="disabled-yes">Yes
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="disabled" id="disabled-no">No
    </label>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('#disabled-radio-btn').click(function (e) {
    if ($('#disabled-no:checked').length) {
        $('#SSDI').hide();
    }
    else {
        $('#SSDI').show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

should be `$('#disabled-no').is(':checked')` in the `if` statement to check if the radio button is checked.

```js
$('#disabled-radio-btn').click(function (e) {

    if ($('#disabled-no').is(':checked')) {
        $('#SSDI').hide();
    }
    else {
        $('#SSDI').show();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" id="disabled-radio-btn">
    <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="disabled" id="disabled-yes">Yes
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="disabled" id="disabled-no">No
    </label>
</div>

<div id="SSDI">SSDI THING</div>
```

**update**: https://jsfiddle.net/7hrbcmnb/2/

use event delegation when declaring the click event

`$(document).on('click', '#disabled-radio-btn', function (e) {});`

Comment: Also note that you can reduce the `if` statement to just `$('#SSDI.toggle(!$('#disabled-no').is(':checked'));`

Comment: @indubitablee  Thanks, however this isn't my issue. Somehow Bootstrap is effecting my click events. On first click, both radio buttons are evaluating to false.
See fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/7hrbcmnb/

Comment: @noclist, i updated my answer with the scenario in your jsfiddle

Comment: @indubitablee perfect, thank you. so, we need event delegation here because the bootstrap plugin script is in a different scope than my own, correct?

Comment: @noclist yup, thats what i think. also note Rory's above comment if you want to simplify the if statement. his suggestion is quite elegant.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `val()` method with the `checked` attribute.

```
if($("#disabled-no:checked").val())
```

```js
$('#disabled-radio-btn').click(function (e) {

    if ($('#disabled-no:checked').val()) {
        $('#SSDI').hide();
    }
    else {
        $('#SSDI').show();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" id="disabled-radio-btn">
    <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="disabled" id="disabled-yes">Yes
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="disabled" id="disabled-no">No
    </label>
</div>

<div id="SSDI">SSDI THING</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, the issue I'm having is different. See fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/7hrbcmnb/
The bootstrap button plugin is effecting my initial click.